# How to perform a second query if first query is empty in mysql and php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have an html form that pass values to a php file that performs a query and display the results.
Now I want that if in this first query the result is empty (0 rows), exactly the same query performs but over another table and display results.

Here is the code that performs the first query:

```
<?php 

echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr>
<th>R1</th>
<th>R2</th>
<th>R3</th>
<th>R4</th>
<th>R5</th>
</tr>";


class TableRows1 extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
function __construct($it1) {
    parent::__construct($it1, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
}

function current() {
    return "<td style='width: 70px;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
}

function beginChildren() {
    echo "<tr>";
}

function endChildren() {
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
}
}

if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $feature = $_POST['R1'];
    $feature2 = $_POST['R2'];
    $feature3 = $_POST['R3'];
    $feature4 = $_POST['R4'];
    $feature5 = $_POST['R5'];
};

$feature = $_POST['R1'];
$feature2 = $_POST['R2'];
$feature3 = $_POST['R3'];
$feature4 = $_POST['R4'];
$feature5 = $_POST['R5'];

$values = [$feature, $feature2, $feature3, $feature4, $feature5];


$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

try {


$conn1 = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt1 = $conn1->prepare(

"SELECT
R1, 
R2, 
R3, 
R4, 
R5, 
FROM table
WHERE
R1 = ?
AND
R2 = ?
AND
R3 = ?
AND
R4 = ?
AND
R5 = ?");

$stmt1->bindParam(1, $feature, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt1->bindParam(2, $feature2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt1->bindParam(3, $feature3, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt1->bindParam(4, $feature4, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt1->bindParam(5, $feature5, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt1->execute();


// set the resulting array to associative
$result1 = $stmt1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach(new TableRows1(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt1->fetchAll())) as $k1=>$v1) {
    echo $v1;
}
}
catch(PDOException $e1) {
echo "Error: " . $e1->getMessage();
}
$conn1 = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I honestly do not know where and how to place the second query, any ideas and guidance I will appreciate very much!

Comment: Why not execute just one query over both tables, but only show the results of the second table if the first is blank?

Comment: @Strawberry to perform a query to multiple tables, as far as I know they must have rows in common, in this case the two tables do not have rows in common

Comment: That's not quite the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Strawberry's advice, I managed to solve it with the following query:

```
SELECT 
NULL AS field1,
table1.R1,
table1.R2,
table1.R3,
table1.R4,
table1.R5,
FROM 
table1
WHERE
table1.R1 = ?
AND
table1.R2 = ?
AND
table1.R3 = ?
AND
table1.R4 = ?
AND
table1.R5 = ? 
UNION ALL
SELECT
table2.field1, 
table2.R1,
table2.R2,
table2.R3,
table2.R4,
table2.R5
FROM table2
WHERE 
table2.R1 = ?
AND
table2.R2 = ?
AND
table2.R3 = ?
AND
table2.R4 = ?
AND
table2.R5 = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

By way of example; I'm not saying it's pretty, but I hope that's more of a weakness of the data model than my coding skills...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_b;

CREATE TABLE table_a(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE table_b(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO table_b VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM
     ( SELECT 1 source, id FROM table_a
        UNION
       SELECT 2, id FROM table_b
     ) x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MIN(source) min_source
         FROM 
            ( SELECT 1 source, id FROM table_a
               UNION
              SELECT 2, id FROM table_b
            ) n
     ) y
    ON y.min_source = x.source;
    
+--------+----+
| source | id |
+--------+----+
|      2 |  1 |
|      2 |  2 |
|      2 |  3 |
+--------+----+
```